# C# SQL query works in SSMS but not C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hey all I am using the following query in my C# program:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlDevConnection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Q, con);
con.Open();

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val0", buildTblVal.ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", recordID);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Dispose();
con.Close();
```

Seems I am getting an error of **Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.** when it gets to the **command.ExecuteNonQuery();**.

The query looks like this:

```
UPDATE 
    [tTrip] 
SET 
    @val0 
WHERE 
    RequestID = @val1
```

And when its populated it looks like this:

```
UPDATE 
  tT 
SET 
  RequestType=75,
  TripLead='Barker, Bob',
  Category=2,
  RequestDate='2016-12-15',
  ApproxDate='2016-12-15',
  AtC='yes',
  TStatus='New',
  LastModifiedBy='bob\barker',
  LastModifiedDate='2017-04-18 10:24 AM'
WHERE 
  RequestID = 779
```

I get the error of:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

However, when I copy that same query and paste it into SSMS it runs just fine.

What would I be missing?

Comment: You need to show us `Q`

Comment: LastModified is missing the opening quote '

Comment: You also need to show us buildTblVal

Comment: you missed a single quote for `LastModifiedBy` column

Comment: `SET @val0 ` - You cannot parameterize an identifier like a column name, you need to construct that part manually.

Comment: Parameters are values. They cannot contain sql parts like clauses or object names, etc. That is why it fails.

Comment: @Mangist correct that. That was my fault.

Comment: @StealthRT and you're still getting the syntax error?

Comment: @Mangist yes...

Comment: See the answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameters are value placeholders, they cannot be sql clauses, statements, etc. That is why it fails because you cannot pass in a whole string for the SET clause as a parameter.

For example, this is how parameters should be used.

```
UPDATE 
  tT 
SET 
  RequestType = @requestType,
  TripLead = @tripLead,
  Category = @category
  -- etc
WHERE 
  RequestID = @requestID
```

---

On a side note it is considered best practice to wrap your instances in `using` blocks where the type implements `IDisposable`. This ensures that resources are always freed even in the event of an Exception. When working with databases this is a must as it guarantees that connections are not left open until garbage disposal runs (which is non-deterministic).

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlDevConnection"].ConnectionString))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Q, con))
{
    con.Open();
    // add parameters correctly based on above example
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", recordID);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```